# Polynomial Expansion from scratch with numpy/python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, regression, polynomials

I am building a polynomial regression without using Sklearn.
I'm having trouble with Polynomial Expansion of features right now.

I have a dataframe with columns A and B. 
When I imported and ran PolynomialFeatures(degree of 2) from Sklearn, I found that it returns 6 different features.

I understand that 2 features became 6 features because it is (A + B + Constant)*(A + B + Constant)

which becomes A2 + 2AB + 2AC + 2BC + B2 + C2, 6 different features. I am trying to recapitulate this with Python and Numpy.

As there is constant c, I created a new column C to my dataframe. However, I am very stuck on how to proceed after this. I tried for loop for (number of features * degree #) times but got confused for the combination of features.

'''

```
    def polynomial_expansion(features_df, order):

        return expanded_df
```

'''

Can someone help me out? What would be Python/Numpy/Pandas method I can use for this situation?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a simple example of what you need to do in order to create your polynomial features from scratch. The first part of the code creates the result from Scikit Learn:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'x': [2],
    'y': [5],
    'z': [6]})

p = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2).fit(df)
f = pd.DataFrame(p.transform(df), columns=p.get_feature_names(df.columns))
print('deg 2\n', f)
p = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3).fit(df)
f = pd.DataFrame(p.transform(df), columns=p.get_feature_names(df.columns))
print('deg 3\n', f)
```

The result looks like:

```
deg 2
      1    x    y    z  x^2   x y   x z   y^2   y z   z^2
0  1.0  2.0  5.0  6.0  4.0  10.0  12.0  25.0  30.0  36.0
deg 3
      1    x    y    z  x^2   x y   x z   y^2   y z   z^2  x^3  x^2 y  x^2 z  x y^2  x y z  x z^2    y^3  y^2 z  y z^2    z^3
0  1.0  2.0  5.0  6.0  4.0  10.0  12.0  25.0  30.0  36.0  8.0   20.0   24.0   50.0   60.0   72.0  125.0  150.0  180.0  216.0
```

Now to create a similar feature without Scikit Learn, we can write our code like this:

```py
row = [2, 5, 6]

#deg = 1
result = [1]
result.extend(row)

#deg = 2
for i in range(len(row)):
    for j in range(len(row)):
        res=row[i]*row[j]
        if res not in result:
            result.append(res)
print("deg 2", result)

#deg = 3
for i in range(len(row)):
    for j in range(len(row)):
            for z in range(len(row)):
                res=row[i]*row[j]*row[z]
                if res not in result:
                    result.append(res)
print("deg 3", result)
```

The result looks like:

```
deg 2 [1, 2, 5, 6, 4, 10, 12, 25, 30, 36]
deg 3 [1, 2, 5, 6, 4, 10, 12, 25, 30, 36, 8, 20, 24, 50, 60, 72, 125, 150, 180, 216]
```

To get the same results recursively, you can use the following code:

```py
row = [2, 5, 6]
def poly_feats(input_values, degree):
    if degree==1:
        if 1 not in input_values:
            result = input_values.insert(0,1)
        result=input_values
        return result
    elif degree > 1:
        new_result=[]
        result = poly_feats(input_values, degree-1)
        new_result.extend(result)
        for item in input_values:
            for p_item in result:
                res=item*p_item
                if (res not in result) and (res not in new_result):
                    new_result.append(res)
        return new_result

print('deg 2', poly_feats(row, 2))
print('deg 3', poly_feats(row, 3))
```

And the results will be:

```
deg 2 [1, 2, 5, 6, 4, 10, 12, 25, 30, 36]
deg 3 [1, 2, 5, 6, 4, 10, 12, 25, 30, 36, 8, 20, 24, 50, 60, 72, 125, 150, 180, 216]
```

Also, if you need to use Pandas data frame as an input to the function, you can use the following:

```py
def get_poly_feats(df, degree):
    result = {}
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        result[index] = poly_feats(row.tolist(), degree)
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. If possible, may I ask for a little more hint on elaborating for loop? The pattern I see now is repeating the nested for loop n(number of degree) times but I can't figure out how to incorporate that into the function (as nested loop).

Comment: Hi Daniel, I just added a new function to avoid the nested loops.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thank you for your kindness. If possible, may I ask for one more help? I'm curious what should I fix if I want to use Pandas dataframe as an input & output instead of list.

Comment: You can write a for loop to iterate over the rows in a Pandas data frame, convert them to lists and run this function for each row of data. I'll update the code later to include that as well.

Comment: Thank you Nathan, I will also keep brainstorm by myself but i will really appreciate if you update the code.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out still... I will really appreciate any update

Comment: Oh god. I totally overthinked for Pandas part - didn't consider re-using the function you already wrote. Thank you so much Nathan! This really helped me a lot for learning.